# Get ticker prices for all symbols via websockets for Binance Futures

Tags: go, binance

I would like to subscribe to Binance's Futures websocket price feed to receive the current ticker prices for all symbols with the Binance GO api. The [documentation states](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2/futures#WsAllBookTickerServe) that the `WsAllBookTickerServe` returns all ticker prices. However, `event` is a [WsBookTickerEvent object](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2/futures#WsBookTickerEvent) which is a struct and it holds the data of a single pair. While I think I should receive a list of objects. When I try to print `fmt.Println(event.Symbol)`, nothing happens but the code runs without any errors. What am I doing wrong? Am I processing `doneC` wrong? I followed the docs and don't get any errors so maybe I am close, just can't read the result properly.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "github.com/adshao/go-binance/v2"
)

func getBinanceTickers() {
    wsBookTickerHandler := func(event *binance.WsBookTickerEvent) {
        fmt.Println(event.Symbol)
    }

    errHandler := func(err error) {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    doneC, _, err := binance.WsAllBookTickerServe(wsBookTickerHandler, errHandler)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    <-doneC
}

func main() {
    go getBinanceTickers()
    for {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

}
```

Comment: The library is using this endpoint when you use `WsAllBookTickerServe` `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!bookTicker` perhaps this doesn't exists. Couldn't find any reference to this endpoint in Binance documentation.